# map probability to threshold with boost

Tags: c++, boost, chi-squared, probability-density

I need to calculate the probability of missed detection for a certain threshold t, where the chi square distribution has non centrality parameter lambda.

I tried to understand the boost probability fun, but so far I did not come up with something working.

```
boost::math::non_central_chi_squared mydist(n, lambda);
boost::math::cdf(mydist, t); // probability that value is taken less than or equal
boost::math::cdf(complement(mydist, t)); // probability that value is taken greater or equal
```

gives to probability that a pick is below or above t.

**How do I get reverse mapping a given probability `p` to a threshold `t`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
boost::math::chi_squared mydist(n);
x = boost::math::qunatile(complement(mydist, pfa));


boost::math::non_central_chi_squared mydist(n, lambda);
y = boost::math::quantile(mydist, pmd);
```

where `pfa` is the probability of false alert and `pmd` the probability of missed detection